# C# Constraints on type parameters with Inheritance

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

I have public class type `Controller` where I make some miracles

```
public class ApiController : Controller { ... }
```

And now I want to make more miracles using constraints

Needs class `ApiController : Controller` with constraints on type parameters

Probably it might look like this, but **this code doesn't work**:

```
public class ApiController : Controller<T> where T : class {
  public T Response;
}
```

How we can do it, if It's possible in C#?

Comment: There is no generic class Controller<T> so it's normal it is not working.

Comment: It sounds like you want to make your own `BaseController<T>` class and have `ApiController` inherit from that. But it's not really clear what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correct ,you might want to do like this.

If you want to constraints on type parameters, you need to add generic on your class instead of on inherit class

```
 public class ApiController<T> : Controller where T : class
 {
     public T Response;
 }
```

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Comment: Maybe you know - can I internalize  T Response in base class? - it might look like this public `class ApiController<T> : Controller where T : class
 {
     public T Response = new T();
 }`

Comment: You can try to add `new()` on be generic constraints, like    `class ApiController<T> : Controller where T : class,new()
    { public T Response = new T(); }`

Comment: Man, this is awesome! You made my life full of meaning :)